# Return XML from SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, nested, for-xml-path

I want to generate XML from a SQL query in this format:

```
<Reports>
    <Header>
        <PrintedBy>XYZ </PrintedBy>
        <PrintedDate>22/01/2015</PrintedDate>
        <Image>C:/Img/a.png</Image>
        <Title>Title</Title>
    </Header>
    <Report>
        <Name>123</Name>
        <UserName></UserName>
        <Remarks></Remarks>
        <IPAddress>0.0.0.0</IPAddress>
        <DateCreated>2016-02-24T18:32:11.803</DateCreated>
        <AppID>BOS</AppID>
        <AppVersion>0.0.3.0</AppVersion>
        <LastLoggedin>2016-06-23T16:04:07.167</LastLoggedin>
    </Report>
    <Report>
        <Name>123</Name>
        <UserName></UserName>
        <Remarks></Remarks>
        <IPAddress>0.0.0.0</IPAddress>
        <DateCreated>2016-02-25T10:22:34.623</DateCreated>
        <AppID>BOS</AppID>
        <AppVersion>0.0.3.0</AppVersion>
        <LastLoggedin>2016-06-23T16:04:07.167</LastLoggedin>
    </Report>
</Reports>
```

Header row should be printed only once, should not repeat with each report row.

Comment: And what have you tried ?

Comment: For some reason, I'm not able to post my Query here.. even though i pasted it as code in a new paragraph..

Comment: @PavanPuligandla add some example, "fake" data

Comment: If you must use SQL, you should be be able to generate that query with a select query with the for xml option.

Comment: @Shungo, My sincere apologies for that, It solved my problem and now i marked it as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the next question you should please provide a table structure and sample data...

In this answer I use a table variable to provide the header's data.

And - as I'm not willing to type in your data - I **read** your XML **into a temp table** and use this temp table to create your select. The final `SELECT` is the one you need. You'll have to adapt this to your needs...

#### Attention

The datetime-format in your header is culture specific! Avoid that. If it wasn't the 22th of January but the 9th of January one could not know what is the month and what is the day. In XML it is - in most cases - ISO 8601.

```
DECLARE @headerTbl TABLE(PrintedBy VARCHAR(100),PritnedDate DATETIME,[Image] VARCHAR(100),Title VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @headerTbl VALUES('XYZ',{d'2015-01-22'},'C:/Img/a.png','Title');

DECLARE @xml XML=
'<Reports>
    <Header>
        <PrintedBy>XYZ </PrintedBy>
        <PrintedDate>2015-01-22</PrintedDate>
        <Image>C:/Img/a.png</Image>
        <Title>Title</Title>
    </Header>
    <Report>
        <Name>123</Name>
        <UserName></UserName>
        <Remarks></Remarks>
        <IPAddress>0.0.0.0</IPAddress>
        <DateCreated>2016-02-24T18:32:11.803</DateCreated>
        <AppID>BOS</AppID>
        <AppVersion>0.0.3.0</AppVersion>
        <LastLoggedin>2016-06-23T16:04:07.167</LastLoggedin>
    </Report>
    <Report>
        <Name>123</Name>
        <UserName></UserName>
        <Remarks></Remarks>
        <IPAddress>0.0.0.0</IPAddress>
        <DateCreated>2016-02-25T10:22:34.623</DateCreated>
        <AppID>BOS</AppID>
        <AppVersion>0.0.3.0</AppVersion>
        <LastLoggedin>2016-06-23T16:04:07.167</LastLoggedin>
    </Report>
</Reports>';

SELECT Rep.value('Name[1]','varchar(max)') AS Name
      ,Rep.value('UserName[1]','varchar(max)') AS UserName
      ,Rep.value('Remarks[1]','varchar(max)') AS Remarks
      ,Rep.value('IPAddress[1]','varchar(max)') AS IPAddress
      ,Rep.value('DateCreated[1]','datetime') AS DateCreated
      ,Rep.value('AppID[1]','varchar(max)') AS AppID
      ,Rep.value('AppVersion[1]','varchar(max)') AS AppVersion
      ,Rep.value('LastLoggedin[1]','datetime') AS LastLoggedin
INTO #tmpYourTable
FROM @XML.nodes('/Reports/Report') AS One(Rep);

SELECT (
         SELECT *
         FROM @headerTbl
         FOR XML PATH('Header'),TYPE
       )
       ,(
         SELECT *
         FROM #tmpYourTable
         FOR XML PATH('Report'),TYPE
       )
FOR XML PATH('Reports')

GO
DROP TABLE #tmpYourTable
```